# Replacing information between two Character breaks

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to replace information which is between two character breaks "|"

The data in the column

```
Parameters_Sent_To_Procdure|Information_to_replace_|Put_the_existing_information_back
```

So I want to put the existing parameters back replace the information between the two **Pipes "|"** then put the information after the second pipe back

Comment: provide work you have tried

Comment: Do you use oracle or mysql? Because these are 2 different products with different implementations of sql. What have you done so far? For mysql I'm pretty sure that this question has been answered before in SO.

Comment: @Shadow I removed the extra MYSQL Tag

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam I added work i have tried

Comment: You should fix your data model. Storing delimited values like that is a really bad design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to replace information which is between two character breaks "|"

The easiest way is to **extract** the substring and **concatenate** it with your **desired value** which you want to **replace** with and then **concatenate everything back** using:

- **SUBSTR**
- **INSTR**

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS
  2    (SELECT 'Parameters_Sent_To_Procdure|Information_to_replace_|Put_the_existing_information_back' str
  3    FROM dual
  4    )
  5  SELECT SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '|', 1,1) -1)
  6    || ''
  7    || SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '|', 1, 1) + 1,
  8                   instr(str, '|', 1, 2) -
  9                  instr(str, '|', 1, 1) -1) AS "new_str"
 10  FROM data;

new_str
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Parameters_Sent_To_ProcdureInformation_to_replace_
```

**How the query works:**

```
SELECT SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '|', 1,1) -1)
```

The above SUBSTR extracts the first part of the string, i.e. from the **beginning** of the string to the **first occurrence** of `|`.

```
'<Here goes the string you want to replace>'
```

The above should be your new value.

```
SUBSTR(str, instr(str, '|', 1, 1) + 1, 
            instr(str, '|', 1, 2) - 
            instr(str, '|', 1, 1) -1)
```

The above SUBSTR extracts the last part of the string, i.e. from the **second occurrence** of `|` till the **end** of the string.

Comment: Brilliant . Thank you for the great description of what you are doing